# Solving the BVP using finite differences and intuition regarding the form of the numerical solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, intuition, boundary-value-problem

Suppose we have $u'' + u'  =0$ where $x \in (0,1)$ with the boundary conditions $u(0) =0, u(1)  =1$.

We consider the BVP finite difference approximation
$\frac{u_{j+1}  -2u_{j} + u_{j-1}}{h^2} + \frac{u_{j+1} - u_{j-1}}{2h} = 0$ for $j=1, \ldots , (N-1)$. with $u_{0} = 0, u_{N} = 1$

Say $U_{j}$ is an approximation to $u(x_{j})$, where $x_{j}  =jh$ with $h = \frac{1}{N}$.

is there some intuition to show that the solution is of the form $U_{j} = ar^j + b$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$ with $r \neq 1$ and $r$ satisfying $(2+h)r^2 - 4r + (2-h) = 0$.